# ActiveMQ Classic client connections keep disconnecting

Tags: tcp, activemq-classic

I'm using `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` from ActiveMQ Classic 5.16.4 with the TCP protocol from my JMS client. The JMS broker is ActiveMQ Classic 5.16.5. No matter what parameters I can think of I cannot seem to prevent or delay the client from disconnecting. Using the `failover` layer does functionally help, but the environment settings result in a log message every time they reconnect, and with 8+ clients at once, it's a ton of bloat.

I've tried looking at the [tcp transport reference](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/documentation/tcp-transport-reference) (as well as the [source code](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/cd5c993eed4e31edd0e6715b431e068889ccaab3/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/tcp/TcpTransport.java#L56) to see if there were any other settings I could use), and none of the settings have helped. I've tried `keepAlive` set to `true`, `soTimeout` set to `0`, `soWriteTimeout` set to `0`, and `connectionTimeout` set to `0`.

I'm formatting my URIs in the form of `tcp://hostname:XXXXX?connectionTimeout=0&keepAlive=true`, which is correct as far as I'm aware.

The network situation is inherently obscenely complicated due to the nature of this work. The old scenario is both client and broker are on the same VM, and did not have issues with disconnecting, nor had logging overflowing when failover was enabled. The current scenario, the one with the issue described above, is with the broker in a Kubernetes container.

EDIT: I should probably mention the broker URL: `tcp://hostname:XXXXX?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&transport.useInactivityMonitor=false`.

Comment: What are the error logs telling about why the client disconnected?

Comment: @TimBish There aren't any errors as far as I can tell, they're just presumably disconnecting from inactivity.

Comment: @JustinBertram 5.16.4 on the client side and 5.16.5 on the broker side

Comment: Have you ruled out network or firewall issues? Does the client application fail the same way if it's running on the same machine as the broker?

Comment: @JustinBertram the network situation is inherently obscenely complicated due to the nature of this work. The old scenario is both client and broker are on the same VM, and did not have issues with disconnecting, nor had logging overflowing when failover was enabled. 

The current scenario, the one with the issue described above, is with activemq in a kubernetes container.

Comment: My hunch is that the problem is in your environment somewhere and not with the client or broker. I'm not a networking expert, but I think you should be able to put a sniffer on the TCP connection and get a better idea of what exactly is going on.